# Is the following algorithm for finding the minimum diameter spanning tree correct?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

> You are given an undirected and unweighted connected graph $G(V, E)$ for which you've been asked to find a spanning tree that has minimum diameter.

I have an idea but I'm not sure if it's a correct one. Can you give me a feedback?

The algorithm:

`let T be an empty forest of trees
for v in V
    color v white
for v in (max-to-min-sort V by degree)
    color v gray
    for u in adj(v)
        if u is white
            add (v, u) to T
            mark u gray
    mark v black`

The algorithm works on the same principal as Kruskal's algorithm for a MST.

Thank you for your time

Comment: From what I can see, it does yield a tree (provided $G$ is connected).  I would try applying the algorithm to regular graphs and see if it does what you want.  I'm skeptical that it gives a min-diameter tree... and I suspect a counter-example can be found among regular graphs.  (I haven't been able to find one yet myself though.)

Comment: The reason I think a regular-graphs are where to look is because your algorithm tries to make use of high (relative) degree vertices.  But, if the graph is regular, then I can add vertices (the v ones that become black first) in any order I want... and I can add their neighbors in any order I want.

Comment: Do not waste your time - the algorithm is extremely buggy. You can see how much using the "Petersen graph". And it does not even builds a tree : /